# a read_only_fields not being recognized in my views.py

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to get these fields in the response of my endpoint, but the view isn't receiving the parameter read_only_fields, just the one in fields.

> Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ('email',
              'password',
              'firstName',
              'middleName',
              'firstSurname',
              'lastSurname',)
    read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_doctor')
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 5}}
```

> UserView:

```
class ManageUserView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """Manage the authenticated user"""
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    authentication_classes = (authentication.TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_object(self):
        return (self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add those fields in your `fields` section of `UserSerializer`

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
      model = get_user_model()
      fields = ('email',
                'password',
                'firstName',
                'middleName',
                'firstSurname',
                'lastSurname','is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_doctor',)
      read_only_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_doctor')
      extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True, 'min_length': 5}}
```

Comment: This solves it, you can also put it manually in the extra_kwargs